# Insert data into nested form with play framework and Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I would like to create a form, where users update their previously inserted values. I.e. I get the data from the database and create form data from this. I am unable to `map` the values from the database to the `Form`.

This is a stripped down version of my data.
`Registration` is data from the database and `UpdateData` is the case class for the form.

```
case class Car (
  hasCar: Boolean,
  trailerHitch: Boolean
)

case class Registration(
    id: Long,
    car: Car,
    comment: String
)

case class UpdateData(
  car: Car,
  comment: String
)
```

`updateForm` is defined inside the `UpdateController` (not shown).

```
val updateForm = Form[UpdateData](
    mapping(
        "car" -> mapping(
            "hasCar" -> boolean,
            "trailerHitch" -> boolean
            )(Car.apply)(Car.unapply),
        "comment" -> text
    )(UpdateData.apply)(UpdateData.unapply)
)
```

I would like to fill out the `updateForm` of type `Form[UpdateData]` with data from a `registration` of type `Registration`.
This data is used in a form that is used to update the previously entered values.
Hence, the name `updateForm`.

The problem is that I don't know how to fill in the *nested* structure of the `Form[UpdateData]`.

```
// NOT WORKING
def makeUpdateFormDataFromRegistration(registration: Registration) =
    updateForm.bind(Map(
        "car" -> Map(
            "hasCar" -> registration.car.hasCar.toString,
            "trailerHitch" -> registration.car.trailerHitch.toString),
        "comment" -> registration.comment))
```

The error is this:

```
overloaded method value bind with alternatives:
[error]   (data: play.api.libs.json.JsValue)play.api.data.Form[controllers.UpdateData] <and>
[error]   (data: Map[String,String])play.api.data.Form[controllers.UpdateData]
[error]  cannot be applied to (scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]])
```

I understand that `updateForm.bind` requires a `Map[String,String]`, but I don't know how I would create such a structure for the nested `updateForm`.

How do I bind data to this nested `updateForm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested values require a dot separator: 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#Nested-values

```
updateForm.bind(Map(
    "car.hasCar" -> registration.car.hasCar.toString,
    "car.trailerHitch" -> registration.car.trailerHitch.toString,
    "comment" -> registration.comment))
```